# how to get response from lambda function into ajax call using api url

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

i created lambda function and api (get method) then i mapped them and deploy.

api-url:https://**********.execute-api.*********.amazonaws.com/test  when i open this url i got below output.

```
{"statusCode": 200, "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "body": "{\"message\": \"new subject area added successfully\"}"}
```

**lambda function:**

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message={
        'message':'new subject area added successfully'
    }


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        'body': json.dumps(message)
    }
```

Ajax call :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function addSubjectArea() {
    alert("going to call ajax");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://37l42zsugg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test',
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success:function(response){
            alert(response)
            },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error occurred while get data");
        }
        });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    addSubjectArea();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>api call from ajax methoid</h2></div>


</body>
</html>
```

but from ajax call it is going to enter into error section

case-2 :

my cloudFormation-template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  hello

  Sample SAM Template for hello

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello2
            Method: get

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

@@@@
api Resource  is generated successfully and when  tried to enable cors.

few things going to fail why?

[image]

any suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: `message` is not defined in your lambda function.

Comment: i edited my code

Comment: Whats the error code? At a glance this is likely a CORS issue.

Comment: yaaa got it after enabling cors option

Comment: Macrin could see question at end  .  when i tried to enable cors few thing going to fail for api created from cloud formation lambda

Comment: Your answer is literally in the screenshot make the changes as it suggests..... for CORS to work properly you need to have some header mappings which the preflight request uses to traverse the different origins.